# Search SubStrings between defined Strings or at the end of defined strings with Vbscript compatible Regular expression

Tags: regex, vbscript, delimiter

I do have to parse specific Information from Report headers in Text Format
Since I do have to perform this through Regular expressions in VB Script I cannot make use of the Look Ahead features of Regex.

Typical use cases to cover for Regular expressions would be

1) `User Name : Clark Kent`
Extracted by Regex: "`Clark Kent`" for any line Starting with "`User Name :`"
2) `User Name  Clark Kent`
Extracted by Regex: "`Clark Kent`" for any line Starting with "`User Name`"  and delete all leading and trailing blanks from "   `Clark Kent`    "
3) `User Name: Clark Kent         Sample ID : 1234`
Extracted by Regex: "`Clark Kent`" from any line starting with "`Clark Kent`" and Ending with "`SampleID :`"

Any Help for this example would be highly appreciated

Comment: I tried to find examples and studied the command reference, but almost all hints for this hint point to LOOKBEHIND , but this is not available in VB

Comment: All three of your examples start with "User Name" so I don't fully understand the third scenario. How is this different?

Comment: Scenario 1 and 2 should find anything behind the identifier "User Name" or "User Name :"  Scenario 3: Find anything  BETWEEN "Clark Kent" and the string(identifier) "SampleID :"

Answer (score 1):

My regex skills aren't the greatest but this pattern works for your three examples. It currently only looks for and returns `<first name><space><last name>`, but it could be adapted to handle more complicated scenarios.

```
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "^User Name\s*:?\s*(\w+\s\w+)\s*(?:Sample ID)?"
    Set Matches = .Execute(strLine)
End With

If Matches.Count > 0 Then strName = Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
```